# Why is this bash/shell script removing duplicate characters from a string?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script which asks for a project name which I then want to convert that name to a safe directory name. I'm using the following:

```
echo "Please enter the name of the new project (eg My New Project):"
read -r project_name

project_directory=$(echo "$project_name" | tr -s '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr -s '[:space:]')
```

I thought this had been working fine but I noticed today that if I enter a word which has 2 or more characters together then the duplicate letters are also removed.

```
Room = rom
Running = runing
```

Just a little confused as to why, I was under the impression that the script would convert uppercase characters to lowercase and spaces would be removed, but apparently not. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's what `tr -s` does.  From the man page:

> #### -s, --squeeze-repeats
>
> replace each sequence of a repeated character that is listed in the last specified SET, with a single occurrence of that character

If you only want it to convert upper to lower, remove the `-s`:

```
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```